# Regular expression selection of last two folder path names

Tags: regex, perl, directory, sublimetext3, filepath

Im working in perl but I am having some issues with cutting out the other folder names to leave the last two folder names.

```
Trainings and Events
General Office\Archive
General Office\Office Opperations\Contacts
General Office\Office Opperations\Office Procedures\How Tos
public_html\Accordion\.svn\tmp\text-base
```

I would like to remove the folder path names so the folders will end up like this with the last two path names for each:

```
Trainings and Events
General Office\Archive
Office Opperations\Contacts
Office Procedures\How Tos
tmp\text-base
Office Opperations\Contacts
```

Ive read some other stackoverflow that showed the last two folder names picked out, but I cannot reverse the expression. (I will link it if I can find it)

I am using sublime text 3 currently to test my expressions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you want is

```
s/.+\/(.+\/.+)$/$1/g
```

It'll grab the last bit of the folder name and replace the whole string with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?:[^\\]*\\|^)[^\\]*$
```

You actually want "up to two", because otherwise you won't catch "Training and Events". To solve this, I match the two cases separately:

- Either a folder name (any number of non-backslashes) followed by a slash, or start of the string
- Another folder name
- End of string

Comment: Then am I supposed to use grep to put the selection into an array?

Comment: You asked for "Regular expression selection of last two folder path names". That is what the answer does. I don't know what you are supposed to do with it. If you wanted the results in an array, then that should have been the question, no? You also do not specify if your data is in a file or in a string or in an array. I can only assume you want it in Perl because of your tags. Those things would certainly impact the answer.